# How to repopulate Cache after expiration?

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, jboss7.x, infinispan

I've been reading about infinispan... I need to use just plain vanilla cache, no clustering, no secondary hibernate cache.

I understand that after expiration, objects in Cache will be destroyed, what I don't understand is how to refresh those objects just before they get destroyed. I checked the events and I see nothing like this.

I'm aiming to have a Map that holds a JPA result query for a given time, then refresh the results from time to time. This cache is read-only, and need not to passivate or store the entries.

So, how to put new values into the Cache before it expires? I'm guessing that infinispan should provide a way of doing this, or am I missing something? Maybe this logic should be implemented with a `@Scheduler` timer within a `@Singleton` EJB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the things in your cache to ever expire then set a negative *timeToLive* for the cache and they will stay forever. 
Or if you need some things to only expire if they haven't been used for e.g. 5 seconds, then set the *maxIdle* to 5 secs. On every read (*cache.get()*) of that key the *maxIdle* start time is reset, so things never get out of the cache as long as they are used frequently enough.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a bad notion about Cache.

Cache items have an expiration time, so one checks if a given entity is there, if it's not there it means that it has expired, so it's time to load that given value once again. So no need to implement a timer. Additionally the Cache will 'clears itself' when a given item have expired.